# When I apply my css to my anchor element out of which there is div elements it become invisible in my browser

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make an anchor around a div element. Without my css, it seems to work but when I try to apply my css it becomes invisible. I hope you can help me, I tried many options but it didn't work.

This is my scss file:

```
        .right {
        height: 100%;
        grid-column: 5/13;
        display: flex;
        gap: 2rem;

        .item {
            background-position: center top;
            background-size: auto 100%;
            border-radius: .5rem;
            flex-grow: 1;
            transition: width 300ms ease;
            width: 33%;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;

            &:before {
                content: '';
                background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.5872724089635855) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 30%);
                inset: 0;
                position: absolute;

            }

            .vert {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 6rem;
                left: .5rem;
                color: white;
                transform: rotate(-90deg);
                font-size: 1.8rem;
                transition: opacity 200ms ease;

            }

            .horiz {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: space-between;
                color: white;
                font-size: 1.2rem;
                padding: 0 2rem;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 2rem;
                width: 100%;
                opacity: 0;
                transition: opacity 200ms ease;



                .topics {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: column;
                    justify-content: center;
                    align-items: center;

                    strong {
                        font-size: 2rem;
                        font-weight: normal;
                        line-height: 1;
                        color: white;
                        transform: scaleX(0);
                        transition: transform 250ms ease;
                    }



                    strong:after{
                        display: block;
                        content:"";
                        border-bottom: solid 3px white;
                        transform: scaleX(0);
                        transition: transform 350ms ease-in-out
                    }
                    strong:hover:after {
                        transform: scaleX(1);
                    }

                        .link:after{
                            transform-origin:  0% 50%;
                        }



                }
            }

            &:hover {
                width: 100%;

                .vert {
                    opacity: 0;
                    }

                .horiz {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }



        }
    }
}
```

and this is my html, there are some django tags cause my website is based on this framework :

```
        <div class="right">
        {% for album_critique in page_obj %}
        <a href="{% url 'view_review' album_critique.id  %}" >
                <div class="item" style="background-image: url({{album_critique.image.url}})">
                    <div class="vert">{{album_critique.band_name}}</div>
                    <div class="horiz">
                        <div class="topics">
                           <strong class="link">{{album_critique.name}}</strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </a>
```

---

Comment: What do you mean it becomes invisible? Can you clarify?

Comment: my elements do not seem to appear, for example, I cannot see my background image or the content of the strong tags

Comment: Working fine for me, are you sure you are linking the image correctly?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure because when I dont apply css or I delete my anchor tag I can see the background image .